# sql - use LIKE to search two columns at once (first and last name)

Tags: sql

I'm trying to build a search feature on my website. I have search working for usernames and emails, but I'd also like to be able to search based on the users full name. My problem is that first_name and last_name are stored separately, and I'm not sure how to build the query for this. Something like

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name AND last_name LIKE '%$query%'
```

Obviously that's very wrong - any help?

Comment: Which database are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name LIKE '%$query%' AND last_name LIKE '%$query%'
```

Comment: If I search for John Smith, it won't check first_name for John Smith and then last_name for John Smith, returning zero results even if there's a first_name John and last_name Smith?

Comment: For that you should have your condition as `where first_name LIKE '%John%' AND last_name LIKE '%Smith%'`. Or you'll have to split your variable such that first like gets the firstname & second like gets the lastname.

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, try using below query:

For Oracle:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name || ' ' || last_name LIKE '%' || $query || '%';
```

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE first_name + ' ' + last_name LIKE '%' + $query + '%';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you care about performance, you might want to investigate a full-text index.

You also need to think clearly about the functionality.  Do you want "John" to match "Johnson" for instance?  Do you want "Ann" to match "Joanne"?  Your decisions on this functionality can have a big impact on performance.  In general, searching for arbitrary substrings in another string impedes the use of indexes.

The direct answer to your question, though, is provided by Amit.  It should work in any database.